# Which light & Lens I have to buy for taking portfolio session & modeling?

Tags: lens, lighting, strobes, portfolio

I am going to buy a Nikon 3200  because my budget is $850. I am not exposed to photography since now. 
Suggest me a good CAMERA, cheap and worthy LENS, AND if possible a cheap lightning equipment for portfolio shoot, modelling.

Comment: You've already specified the camera you're going to get and the cheapest lens is probably the one that comes with the camera. As far as lighting, you have the sun pretty much year round if you don't live in places like Alaska. As much as I wish it were so, the gear does not make the photographer. Identify the effect you want to capture and then find out how to do it. That will tell you what kind of equipment you need (if any).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuiming you mean things like headshots, fashion, and nudes when you say 'modelling' so with a budget of 850 dollars you won't be able to afford a camera and lights ideal for that.

However there are many techniques you can learn to save on expensive equipment. Ordinary house windows make excellent lighting sources that offer a flattering sideways light during the day, add net curtains or a cloudy day for a softer light. Buying a single large reflector (eith a pro one or a big piece of white card) will allow you to bounce light from a window back onto the model to provide a 'fill'.

On camera flash can still be useful by adding a diffuser. There are some available that will mount on the flash socket  with a short arm holding a small piece of white plastic in front of the popup flash. Old school photographers sometimes tape a piece of white card or paper in front of the flash to get a bounce or diffuse effect.

The best thing to do spend money on, after buying a camera, would be a book or two on photography and lighting, go for ones which provide cheap alternatives to traditional lighting rigs.